# Vue / Vuex: How to properly make a mutation for adding a property nested in object

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a mutation that sets my state of `products` from a backend API when the page loads.  Below is how the data is structured when the mutation runs and populates the `products`.

```
state: 

 products: {
       title: "Television",
       desc: "Here is a tv",
       order_products: [
           {
              inventory_id: 44,
              color: "red"
           },
           {
              inventory_id: 45,
              color: "blue"
           },
           {
              inventory_id: 46,
              color: green,
           }
       ]
    }
```

I need to periodically find a nested product by the `inventory_id` and a add a property `scanned` (eg. `scanned: true`) under the nested `color` field for each inventory item.  I am reading on the proper way to use a mutation to add a property to an Object using Vuex such as this method: `state.obj = { ...state.obj, newProp: 123 } (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)`
 but I don't know how that would work because I am adding a nested property , not just a property to the root of the Object.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to add a reactive property.

Here's one way, with `Vue.set`

```js
const id = '...'
const product = products.order_products.find(p => p.inventory_id === id)
Vue.set(product, 'scanned', true)
```